# How to disable Google Backup and Sync notifications?

Tags: google-drive, notifications

In the past week, every time I boot up Windows 10 (Google Backup and Sync is set to launch at startup), I get the following annoying popup:

[image]

Even if I click "Dismiss", the next time I boot up, it pops up again. Even if I click "Learn more", it still pops up again. Moreover, Google Backup and Sync seems to have no setting to disable notifications.

Please help me get rid of this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have the source code, I don't think there's a way to disable notifications since it seems to be programmed to notify users on startup. Google is forcing users to use the new Google Drive client: https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2021/07/google-drive-backup-and-sync-transition.html and this is one of the ways they have chosen to make the transition smoother (read "irritate users enough to use the new client before the deadline")

Here are a couple of options:

1. Use a third-party Google Drive client. I personally use https://www.insynchq.com/ since it works well for me on all desktop platforms. It's unlikely that these will stop working unless Google somehow changes the way file downloading works as documented in its API (https://developers.google.com/drive)
2. Use then new Google Drive client (formerly called Drive File Stream). If you have any problems with apps not being able to work with files in your google drive, try making the files available offline and it should work fine.

Comment: Sigh...another deprecation. Another one bites the dust!